# Action of an algebraic group is closed.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

I am studying geometric invariant theory and I came to the following question. Let us consider an algebraic  subgroup $G$ of $SL(V)$ with $V$ a $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space. Let us consider the scheme
$$\text{Hom}(W,V)$$
where $W$ is another $k$-vector space of the same dimension.
We have a natural $G$-action on the above scheme given by (on closed points)
$$g\cdot f(w):=g(f(w))$$
Let us consider a closed point an the set of isomorphisms: $$\text{Isom}(W_{k'},V_{k'})\subset \text{Hom}(W_{k'},V_{k'})$$
All the isotropy groups are just the identity as can be trivially checked.  But, is it every orbit closed? I am stuck with this question for days.

Comment: I think that  $(1,0,..,0)$ doe not correspond to an isomorphism...

Comment: A clarifying question: you are asking about orbits inside $Isom$ or inside $Hom$? It was not totally clear to me.

Comment: The orbit of an isomorphism inside Hom